# R, car package unable to load

Tags: r, dependencies, install.packages, r-car

I'm new with R, and I'm having some trouble loading the car library. I use Windows 8.1 (64 bit) and i'm working in 32 bit R environment. I downloaded the library just fine, but when i try to load the `car` library using `library(car)` the message i get is:

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
>   versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
>    there is no package called ‘quantreg’
>    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’

This message came up asking for several other libraries besides `quantreg`. I downloaded some of those other libraries in the hope that it would be enough to run car, but it doesn't stop asking for more libraries.

Has anyone had the same issue? This also happened to some people I know, using different operating systems, mostly Windows, but also Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you did not install the dependencies automatically when you installed `car`. I'm assuming that you tried installing with Rstudio, which does not automatically install dependencies.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171148/how-to-tell-cran-to-install-package-dependencies-automatically) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501507/lib-unspecified-error-in-loadnamespace) should help you to install them automatically.

Try reinstalling with the command `install.packages("car",dependencies=TRUE)`.

Additionally, in the future you can check the [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html) to see the depends, imports, suggests, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Using what you told me and the links to the other posts, i managed to solve the issue. I used the install.packages sentence the way you told me, and chose an Austrian repository, just because. A warning came up saying some dependencies where not available, including quantreg, but it downloaded car. Then, i downloaded quantreg and its dependencies manualy and tried loading car, and it worked.