# How to load google trends package in R

Tags: r, install.packages, google-trends

I want to use google trends in R but it won't even load the package. 
I tried fixing it with a couple of solutions from similar posts:

1. [Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'Rcpp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758129/error-in-loadnamespacename-there-is-no-package-called-rcpp)
2. [lib unspecified & Error in loadNamespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501507/lib-unspecified-error-in-loadnamespace)

Here is the code:

```
> install.packages(gtrendsR)
Error in install.packages : object 'gtrendsR' not found
> install.packages("gtrendsR")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Rafael/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/gtrendsR_1.3.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1067912 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

package ‘gtrendsR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4iqNMv\downloaded_packages
> library("gtrendsR")
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gtrendsR’
```

Comment: In a fresh R session, could you try: `install.packages("gtrendsR",dependencies=TRUE)` to ensure all the dependencies are installed as well

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, ran below commands and it worked.

```
install.packages("readr")
install.packages("colorspace")
install.packages("vctrs")
install.packages("gtrendsR")
```

Comment: This actually worked for me on PC as well!

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion going on your machine.  While I am involved with both packages, [gtrendsR](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gtrendsR) does NOT (directly) depend on [Rcpp](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp).

You can see that by following the links above to see the Depends: and Imports:

One thing you could try is to load the various packages that [gtrendsR](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gtrendsR) depends on see where the error creeps in.

All packages *are* on CRAN and you should have no difficulty sorting your machine out.

Answer (score 0):

you need to hit the install command for R

```
install.packages("readr")
```

after installation ..