# R Tool shiny::runApp()

Tags: r, shiny

While running an application in Shiny, it's showing the following error:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : object 'vI' not found

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501507/lib-unspecified-error-in-loadnamespace

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I got solution for above Problem by means of replacing the versions of Packages called "httpuv" and "Lazy" with New oNES